# Comparing two java class files of Different Versions of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to analyze the modification in Classes of two different version of Eclipse... 
For e.g. In Eclipse 2.0 and Eclipse 2.1 there are 4928 same classes with difference in SLOC per class....

I have tried some opensource software like CLOC for finding change in classes in terms of lines of codes but I am bit more concerned in changes which are affecting functionality...

Comment: you could use diff on linux. On windows it would be possible by running cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two possibilities:

1. Compare the source code and unit tests of these classes (if open-sourced).
2. Use a decompiler (i.e. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/) and compare the decompiled code.

Either way it won't be easy to evaluate how exactly the functionality of the classes changed. A change might be simple refactoring, which changes the code's structure but not the functionality itself.